# Add item to context-menu of icon pinned to the taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, context-menu

Is it possible to add an item to the context-menu displayed when an icon pinned to the taskbar is right-clicked?   Sometimes I'd like to "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Not a duplicate. They **always** want to run as administrator. I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run an application as administrator from the taskbar, left-click its icon while holding down the `Shift` and `Ctrl` keys. A pop-up will appear and asking for Administrator privileges when not logged in as an admin.

If you are doing this while the application is already running, Windows will open a new instance of it with admin rights.