# Accessing Windows 10 taskbar context menu while program is open

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, context-menu

When a program that is pinned to my taskbar is closed, I can hold shift and right-click on the icon to open the context menu:

[image: context menu while program is closed]

However, if the program is open, then the context menu is replaced by a program-dependent menu:

[image: context menu while program is open]

I have found myself needing the default context menu sometimes, such as to open file location or adjust the shortcut properties, while the program is open. (I also sometimes want to run a second instance as an administrator, but the "Similar Questions" sidebar led me to [this awesome solution](https://superuser.com/a/1134442/420621) for that.)

Is there any way to access the default context menu while a program is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right-click the open program's icon.
- You will see the program listed as an entry on the menu that opens.
- Shift+Right-click that entry and you should get the full context menu (tested with Windows 10 1607)

[image: Windows 10 taskbar context menu for open program]